# How to add a redirect from https://myfirstdomain.com/register to https://myseconddomain.com in Azure?

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-functions, azure-api-management

The use case seems plain and simple:
Redirect any requests in the form https://myfirstdomain.com/register to https://myseconddomain.com (note the route "register"). Further Note: https:/myseconddomain.com is an Azure App Service, https://myfirstdomain.com/register used to be an Azure Function.

In the past we have used an Azure Function and "Proxies".
There we could easily setup a proxy with a route template `/register` and then return a 301 Moved permanently response, whereas in the header location we provided the new domain.
Microsoft strongly recommends to move away from Proxies (they will get deprecated in 2025).
I also tried to reenable the feature by adding `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` and value `EnableProxies` for now, but the "Proxies" is still greyed out in the Azure Portal => Should I add proxies.json directly?

Instead we should move to Azure API management (as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#api-management-integration).

How can we achieve the same behaviour as described above in API Management? Or is there yet a easier approach to achieve what I am looking for (Add a CNAME record for the old domain and a permanent redirect in myseconddomain.com?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to easily do this with Azure Front Door, though there is a way in APIM to redirect by using `policy` and also an override option for the `backend` , see [set backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-backend-service-policy) policy.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Yes, I also saw that option with Azure Front Door (AFD). However, in our scenario using AFD seems to be an overkill for one single redirect. :/